# Default colors for Azure DevOps Dashboard pie charts

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to set the default colors for Azure DevOps pie charts on dashboards?

We have a large number of pie charts, and configuring each one individually is challenging.

We'd like to centrally express coloring like marking all Closed user stories as black, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such setting to bulk edit the chart color. You have to edit them one by one currently.

If you really want to have this feature, please submit a suggestion on following site:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21